# MySQL SP Syntax Error in PREPARE stmt

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

This two lines doesn't have any syntax error when i try to save each one separately.
But when i want to save sp with this two lines MySql raise an Error which says the syntax near 'PREPARE stmt from @a' is not correct.

Whyyyyyyyyy? :(
Does is problem of my MySql or PHPMyAdmin ?

```
     SET @a = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ' , dbname , '(A INT, B INT, C INT)');
     PREPARE stmt from @a;
```

Comment: Post your compete SP code used.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATABASE() function and not dbname like:

```
CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ' , DATABASE() , '(A INT, B INT, C INT)');
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4bbfc/2)